# Is it possible to do a Date & Time Calender using jquery-ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried using format: to get the sequence of data in year

example

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datetimePicker" ).datepicker(
    {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'
    });
});
```

Comment: What did you expect? What actually happens?

Comment: It returns me 04/13/2016

Comment: I was expecting 2016-04-13 16:07:00

Comment: Did you  use jquery datepicker ? To set format for datepicker you should change `format` to `dateFormat `

Comment: change in your HTML and write There ` data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" `

Comment: jQuery [Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) only allows selection of date. You would need to use an `DateTimePicker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jQuery `dateTimePicker` for pick date with time.
Datepicker can only pick date.

Download the plugin from [here](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/datetimepicker).

include js and css file in your page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
<script src="jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

And your markup like

```
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
```

**JS:**

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({datepicker:true,timepicker:true});
```

Don't forgot to include `jquery.js` first in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public String setPickedDate() 
{
    //if condition
    if (day.equals(""))
    return day;
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month, Integer.parseInt(day));
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#format" ).change(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
    });
```

Visit https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats